# AWS Regional Disaster Recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I would like to create a mirror image of my existing production environment in another AWS region for disaster recovery.
I know I don't need to recreate resouces such as IAM roles as its a "Global" service. (correct me if I am wrong)
Do I need to recreate key pairs in another region?
How about Launch configurations and Route 53 Records sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch configurations you will have to replicate into the another region as the AMIs, Security Groups, subnets, etc will all be different. Some instance types are not available in all regions so you will have to check that as well.

Route53 is another global thing but you will probably have to fiddle with your records to take advantage of multi-region architecture. If you have the same setup in two different regions you will probably want to implement latency based or geo routing to send traffic to the closest region. [Heres](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/traffic-policies.html) some info on that

As for keys they are per region. But I read somewhere that you could create an AMI from your instance, move that to a new region, and fire an instance off that and as long as you use the same key name your existing key will work but take that with a grain of salt as I haven't tried it nor seen it documented anywhere.

[Heres](https://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Migrate_Resources_To_New_Region.pdf) the official AWS info for migrating